# How to send message to a node websocket using PHP

Tags: php, node.js, websocket

Here is some background info...
I have a system using PHP/Laravel with front-end in Vue.
I create a given transaction and it must be validated by another user. It generates a QRCode which is read by the other user that confirms the transaction.

The thing is I want the user that created the transaction being notified when the other confirms. Now what I do is keep polling with ajax every 5 secs until the transaction is confirmed.

I'm trying to use a websocket to replace the "ugly" polling strategy, but I'm struggling to communicate back the response through the websocket to the user.

The websocket is in node. How can I connect this websocket with PHP (as a client, for instance) just to send a message that I will pass to that specific client that is waiting for the transaction to be confirmed? The main issue here is the communication between the ws and the PHP app.

If I didn't make myself clear enough I can provide more information if needed...

That is the code of my websocket server:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')
const server = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 })

const sockets = []

server.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log('Client connected');
  ws.on('message', message => {
    console.log(`message received: ${message}`);
    
    sockets.forEach((aSocket) => {
      aSocket.send(`Client says: ${message}`)
    });
  });

  sockets.push(ws)
});
```

It broadcasts the message to all connected users, but it's ok for now. Its only for test purpose. As soon as I get to send the message from PHP server I can manage to send the message only to the respective user that generated the transaction.

I have tried using “socket_connect”, “fsockopen” and even “curl”. I don’t know if its not possible or I’m doing something wrong but as far as I went it didn’t work. At most I’ve received an error “Upgrade Required” (when using curl) and “HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request” (when using the others)

Comment: If you really want to do it from PHP, then [start here](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+websocket+client). Or could you do it from the vue front-end part?

Comment: Why don't use just implement event-streams? When server is ready you can tell user and they can close it from their end client-side.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK Interesting approach. I didn’t know about event-stream. I think you’re talking about the javascript EventSource interface, right? But what would be the advantage of using event-stream from polling that same end-point with ajax and setInterval? Thanks.

Comment: If you poll you're re-establishing the request each time you check and that can be expensive with many users checking whereas an event stream they'd connect once and do nothing till alerted. Now some draw-backs user could always leave before event-stream/poll is finished or disconnect; but I'm sure you could sort that by just sending an email as a confirm just incase.

Comment: I use the event-streams to let user know their progress on their servers loading up, if they refresh they can see any pending progress or see that the their servers are online/ready upon refresh and an email to confirm it to.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK I'm just wondering if keep that connection open while the server checks for changes in a loop (then I’ll have a PHP thread running for a long time) wouldn't be worse than making requests periodically. I mean, once PHP is tread-based, if I have many users at the same time, having a connection every 3 seconds that just lasts milliseconds wouldn’t be better than a connection that stands much longer?

Comment: It could be worth benchmarking, my opinion would still stand however as a thread isn't representative of a core and you could host many streams like this without the active need to re-open the connection.

Comment: This should help you see it's quite expensive to re-open that connection with a new request every 3 seconds or even 5->10 if a mass of users were relying on it. Keepalive can help this process be much faster but yeah costly...
https://love2dev.com/img/https-connection-sequence-diagram-817a81c95e51bec4309b6c44eae985aa.png